# How can I loop through this array - PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

This is the `var_dump($options)`

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  'parent_2_children' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '22' (length=2)
      1 => string '24' (length=2)
      2 => string '23' (length=2)
  1 => string '3' (length=1)
  'parent_3_children' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '26' (length=2)
      1 => string '25' (length=2)
      2 => string '27' (length=2)
```

What I have tried up to now is

```
if(!is_null($options))
        {
            foreach($options as $option)
            {
                 if(!array_key_exists('parent_'.$option.'_children',$options))
                 {
                    //if position null output an error
                 }
            }   


        }
```

Print_r() as requested

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [parent_2_children] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 24
            [2] => 23
        )

    [1] => 3
    [parent_3_children] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
            [1] => 25
            [2] => 27
        )

)
```

Comment: What do you want to do while you are looping through it?

Comment: if position null output an error

Comment: Your existing code should be fine for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. An additional check on the nature of the key will reduce the execution, since you have to do the processing only for numeric keys.

```
    if(!is_null($options))
    {
        foreach($options as $key => $option)
        {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                 if(!array_key_exists('parent_'.$option.'_children',$options))
                  {
                       print 'parent_'.$option.'_children does not exist';
                   }
             }
        }   


    }
```

To test the code, try the following array :

```
 $options = array(0 => 2, 'parent_2_children' => array ( 0 => 22, 1 => 24, 2 => 23 ), 1 => 3, 'parent_3_children' => array ( 0 => 26, 1 => 25, 2 => 27 ), 2=>4 );
```

whose print_r output will be :

```
 Array
(
[0] => 2
[parent_2_children] => Array
    (
        [0] => 22
        [1] => 24
        [2] => 23
    )

[1] => 3
[parent_3_children] => Array
    (
        [0] => 26
        [1] => 25
        [2] => 27
    )

[2] => 4
```

)

and, it will output :

```
  parent_4_children does not exist
```

Comment: Right now, it will not output anything, since both array keys of the form parent_'.$option.'_children exists in the array

Answer (score 1):

use `print_r($options)` in staid of `var_dump` it's easier to read..

check if you got a numeric key, then check if the new key exists. Throw an error.

```
if(!is_null($options)) {
    foreach($options as $key => $option) {
        if(is_int($key) && !array_key_exists('parent_'.$option.'_children',$options)) {
           echo 'parent_'.$option.'_children does not exist';
        }
    }   
}
```

Here is a [working example](http://codepad.org/G1iVrCLJ)

Comment: what do you want it to do? I can throw an exception, or echo some text... I'll update. But note that it will only show something when the key doesn't exist

Comment: i'm already echo 'parent_'.$option.'_children'; this. does not work

Comment: the array you provided is a valid array. If you got an invalid key, it will output the message. try pushing a non existing value like `$options[0] = '9999999';` before running the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
if(!is_null($options)){
    foreach($options as $option){
        if(!array_key_exists('parent_'.$option.'_children',$options)){
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
        }
    }   
}
```